Grouping continuous data using window function
So I have a database like this
ITEM   STOCK   DAY   
A      5       2024-08-12
B      2       2024-08-12
C      7       2024-08-12
A      3       2024-08-13
B      2       2024-08-13
C      7       2024-08-13
D      1       2024-08-13
A      3       2024-08-14
B      3       2024-08-15
C      7       2024-08-14
A      3       2024-08-15
B      3       2024-08-15
C      9       2024-08-15
A      2       2024-08-16
B      3       2024-08-16
C      7       2024-08-16
A      5       2024-08-17
B      2       2024-08-17
C      7       2024-08-17
D      3       2024-08-17

What I wanted to do was check countinuous days of item having same stock using window function.
Which expected result will be like this. (Continuous days will be written as CDAYS)
ITEM   CDAYS    DAY_START   DAY_END   
A      0        2024-08-12   2024-08-12
B      1        2024-08-12   2024-08-13  
C      5        2024-08-12   2024-08-17
A      2        2024-08-13   2024-08-15
D      0        2024-08-13   2024-08-13
B      2        2024-08-14   2024-08-16
A      0        2024-08-16   2024-08-16
A      0        2024-08-17   2024-08-17
B      0        2024-08-17   2024-08-17
D      0        2024-08-17   2024-08-17  

I've tried to make my own window function to solve this problem, but failed.
Yet, I did found out what is the problem.
Using SQL like this
create table mytable (ITEM char, STOCK int,  DATE date);
insert into mytable values
('A',    5,    '2024-08-12'),
('B',    2,    '2024-08-12'),
('C',    7,    '2024-08-12'),
('A',    3,    '2024-08-13'),
('B',    2,    '2024-08-13'),
('C',    7,    '2024-08-13'),
('D',    1,    '2024-08-13'),
('A',    3,    '2024-08-14'),
('B',    3,    '2024-08-14'),
('C',    7,    '2024-08-14'),
('A',    3,    '2024-08-15'),
('B',    3,    '2024-08-15'),
('C',    7,    '2024-08-15'),
('A',    2,    '2024-08-16'),
('B',    3,    '2024-08-16'),
('C',    7,    '2024-08-16'),
('A',    5,    '2024-08-17'),
('B',    2,    '2024-08-17'),
('C',    7,    '2024-08-17'),
('D',    3,    '2024-08-17');


SELECT ITEM, STOCK,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM, STOCK ORDER BY DATE) AS Cdays, DATE
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ITEM, DATE

I am getting a result like below
item    stock   cdays   date
A       5       1       2024-08-12
A       3       1       2024-08-13
A       3       2       2024-08-14
A       3       3       2024-08-15
A       2       1       2024-08-16
A       5       2       2024-08-17
B       2       1       2024-08-12
B       2       2       2024-08-13
B       3       1       2024-08-14
B       3       2       2024-08-15
B       3       3       2024-08-16
B       2       3       2024-08-17
C       7       1       2024-08-12
C       7       2       2024-08-13
C       7       3       2024-08-14
C       7       4       2024-08-15
C       7       5       2024-08-16
C       7       6       2024-08-17
D       1       1       2024-08-13
D       3       1       2024-08-17

Looking into ITEM A, cdays should be 1 1 2 3 1 1, not 1 1 2 3 1 2.
How can I modify my SQL so stock of ITEM A from 2014-08-12 and 2014-08-17 is not considered as continuing data?

Think you can look at the LAG and LEAD functions that I think you can combine with the above:  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/   This will let you look at previous and next rows as possibility.

This type of problem is known as Gaps and Islands. Searching with these terms might help you find a solution faster.

There's a good write-up here on gaps and islands and how to tackle with tsql with great examples.

You are not clear in your post what you want as your desired result. You called your second posted table "expected result", but then you point out that it is wrong. Later, you post results in a different format, but then also state that it is wrong. This confusion may have led someone to spend time preparing an answer that may not suit your needs. Please clearly post your actual and correct desired results to eliminate further confusion.

However, if my guess is right, this is a variation of the gaps-and-islands problem where the "gap" is defined by a change in value (in this case stock) over time (date) within a given partition (item). For this variation, the solution is to group by item, stock and the difference between two differently-qualified row_number() functions. The latter calculation forces non-consecutive values in different groups. The question "How do I group on continuous ranges" is nearly identical and you should be able to adapt the accepted answer.

Here's one way derived from Itzik Ben-Gan's NS Ser technique here (my go-to article for gaps and islands problems):
;WITH C1 AS 
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Date) AS rn,
    CASE
        WHEN Stock = LAG(Stock) OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Date) THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS isstart                                              
    FROM dbo.mytable
)
,C2 AS 
(
    SELECT *,
        MAX(isstart * rn)                                       
        OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Date) AS srn
    FROM C1
)
SELECT ITEM, STOCK, DATE, rn - srn + 1 AS seqno                 
FROM C2;


db<>fiddle

